# Controller doesn't call internal function

Tags: java, parameters, itext

I'm trying to make a Java CRUD MVC application. It uses a Sqlite database. One of my functions doesn't want to work. In this function I want to prepare a PDF document that will contain some strings. Everything work well when I try to run this function from separated class, but when I put it into my MVC app it doesn't work.

The console doesn't show any errors, I think that my function doesn't even start. I suppose that it could be a parameter problem?

Here is `controller.java`:

```
public void generuj(){
    akcja = new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event)
        {
            String[] args = null;
            PDF.main(args);
            interfejs.getguzikgeneruj().addActionListener(akcja);   
        }
    };
}
```

Here is Functions.java:

```
public static void generuj() throws DocumentException{
    Document dokument = new Document();
    try {
        PdfWriter.getInstance(dokument, new FileOutputStream("Arkusz Inwentaryzacyjny.pdf"));
        dokument.open();
        Paragraph paragraf = new Paragraph();
        paragraf.add("Arkusz inwentaryzacyjny");
        dokument.add(paragraf);
        dokument.close();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {     
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

And this is working class:

```
package model;

import com.itextpdf.text.Document;
import com.itextpdf.text.DocumentException;
import com.itextpdf.text.Paragraph;
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfWriter;

import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;

public class PDF {

public static void main(String[] args){
    Document dokument = new Document();

    try {
        PdfWriter.getInstance(dokument, new FileOutputStream("Arkusz Inwentaryzacyjny.pdf"));
        dokument.open();
        Paragraph paragraf = new Paragraph();
        paragraf.add("Arkusz inwentaryzacyjny");
        dokument.add(paragraf);
        dokument.close();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (DocumentException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    }
}
```

Comment: Please make your title more descriptive about problem you are facing so other users with similar problem would be able to find it (remember that main purpose of Stack Overflow is to be searchable repository of programming questions and answers)

Comment: Have you tried stepping through the code using the debugger? If so, what did you find? If not, what are you waiting for?

Comment: You seem to be adding your `ActionListener` during `actionPerformed()`. Try to add it after the declaration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would at a minimum re-add the exception handler for DocumentException in the event that your method isn't able to open the pdf document due to the applications context.

This maybe the reason you aren't seeing anything on the console.

```
public static void generujp() throws DocumentException {
    Document dokument = new Document();
    try {
        PdfWriter.getInstance(dokument, new FileOutputStream("example.pdf"));
        dokument.open();
        Paragraph paragraf = new Paragraph();
        paragraf.add("Arkusz inwentaryzacyjny");
        dokument.add(paragraf);
        dokument.close();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (DocumentException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        throw e;
    }
}
```

I also wouldn't add an action listener from within the action.  It would never get added.  Did you intend to have it outside the event handler?

```
public void generuj() {
    ...
    akcja = new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed( ActionEvent event) {
        String[] args = null;
        PDF.main(args);
        //interfejs.getguzikgeneruj().addActionListener(akcja);   
    }
    };
    // new location...
    interfejs.getguzikgeneruj().addActionListener(akcja);   
}
```